# The process '/usr/local/bin/npx' failed with exit code 1

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I have made project using reactjs and firebase and deploy it on firebase via github now when I make any changes and and run npm run built, push code to github then to firebase then below error occurs....what should I do to remove this error.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBmWu.png)

[This comes when I run build and deploy on github action section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULCzT.png)

I am trying to push updates on firebase deployed project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.